# How to reduce the size of the header / footer in microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, footers

I have a problem using Microsoft Word.

I can increase the size of the header by placing some text or images inside, but then it's impossible to reduce it later.

I have tried reducing the margins but it only moves the text and don't reduce the size of the header.

Do someone know how to do it ?

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: I just fired up word, went into the header and did =rand(10), deleted the text and the header section reduced back to its original size. Are you saying if you were to do the same, your header section would remain > 50% of the page?

Comment: it works when I delete what I just added to the header, but when I want to reduce an old header that has already been saved it doesn't work. I can delete the text, but the header will still take the same place on my page

Comment: OK, so that's likely to be a spacing issue. Right-click in the header > Paragraph... and check all the indentation and spacing options are set to 0cm/0pt.

Comment: I just tried this, but it was already set to 0. Even if I reduce the size of the text on the last line it doesn't change, it seems like the space remaining underneath is not text, it's just blank

Comment: Could you prepare 1-page empty document (backup this file, rename it and clear contents) that behaves in the way you described and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce what I have, but when I start over with a new file it works well. In y case, the header has a table inside and maybe the problem comes from this. But the best would be to start over if there is no good solution

Comment: Maybe you have removed the text from the header (and from the table in the header) but the table (empty structure) was not removed?

Comment: I have removed everything with ctrl+A and suppr. I think it is just a bug from the software

Comment: Show the rulers then adjust header spacing accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Display the Page Setup dialog box. For example, you can double-click the vertical ruler. Or you can click the dialog launcher (the little arrow on the bottom righ) of the Page Setup group on the Page Layout tab.

On the Layout tab, make sure that "Vertical alignment" is set to "Top." Also, look a the margins specified on the Margins tab.